# Large number of SYN - RST-ACK

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet, listen

The below screenshot shows the relevant packets I am analysing on my laptop. I am confused as to why source port number is increasing by 1. And also I am not sure what and why this large number of SYC/RSTs are coming from.
[wireshark print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udZDH.png)

Comment: Something on your local machine is continuously connecting to port 9229. But there is no server (listener) at this port, which leads to the RST. The increasing port number is because the previous port cannot be reused for the new connection. Unfortunately there is absolutely nothing known about your machine, what you do with it and what software is running on it. So all what is possible is helping in interpreting what you see, but impossible to tell what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Port 9229 is the default [node.js debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) port.

When you open [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overview/) in your browser, it automatically starts trying to connect to port 9229. If you are not running a node debug server then the debugger client fails to form a TCP connection.

The large number of [SYN] / [RST, ACK] packets are basically the debugging client trying to connect. For each new connection request, the browser requests from a new port increasing it by 1.

In a TCP connection, the [RST] flag is set to reset the connection. It indicates that the receiver should delete the connection without further interaction (source: [TCP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9293.html)). Here, the [RST] flag signifies that port 9229 is not accepting any TCP connections.

You can fix it by closing all the DevTools windows in your browser.
You can also try to run a [simple HTTP server in node](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTP-server/) with the command `node --inspect server.js` and then launch the DevTool window to check that these [RST, ACK] packets are gone and the DevTools window has a made a successful TCP connection.